# Visual Studio : Generate VB.Net code from Class Diagram

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to generate VB.Net code from class diagrams in Visual Studio ?

I'm trying to do it but I could generate only C# code and I didn't find where this can possibly be configured.

Is that possible please ?

Here is a video of what's happening actually.

[Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/keb4muxb1ovhycw/2014-04-06%2022h26_03.mp4)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't use class diagrams very often, but isn't it the other way around, i.e. you create code and then you create a class diagram from it? I.e. class diagram shows a structure of existing code. If you add stuff to a class diagram, it's reflected in code right away. In other words, class diagram is not an abstract smth, it's actually for real. AFAIK, code is generated in whatever language you have selected for the project. If your project is in VB.NET, you will get VB.NET code automatically added/removed for all changes in the class diagram.

Comment: What you're saying is may be true but that is not my question. I'm able to generate C# code from class diagram. All what I need is how to generate the same code but in VB.Net

Comment: I understand your need. Could you please include a screenshot of the feature you are asking about? We may be talking different things here.

Comment: I added a video showing what's happenning